# Superscript in figure caption in bar graphs

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have this code and I want to add Superscript to each bar graph.

```
y=[0.3435 0.36 0.6491 0.6908];
bar(y);
Labels={'A_{1}','A_{2}','A_{3}','A_{4}'};
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:4, 'XTickLabel', Labels);
set(gca,'fontsize',10);
ylabel('Size','FontSize',10)
axis([0 5 0 1])
```

but the subscripts are not applied in the result:(

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get subscripts you can use the LaTeX interpreter. But I don't think the `'xticklabel'` property supports TeX or LaTeX. So: remove your `xticklabel`s and create `text` objects, which does support TeX. To create all text objects at once, you can pass arrays as inputs to the [`text`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) function:

```
y=[0.3435 0.36 0.6491 0.6908];
bar(y);
Labels={'A_{1}','A_{2}','A_{3}','A_{4}'};
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:4, 'XTickLabel', []); %// no ticklabels
set(gca,'fontsize',10);
ylabel('Size','FontSize',10)
axis([0 5 0 1])
text(1:numel(y), -.05*ones(1,numel(y)), Labels, 'interpreter', 'TeX')
%// desired text. Interpreted in TeX. Adjust position changing -0.05 if needed
```

[image]

If you want superscripts instead of subscripts, use

```
Labels={'A^{1}','A^{2}','A^{3}','A^{4}'};
```

Comment: Thanks alot Dr. Mendo :)

Comment: thanks, I have another problem, I changed the words of X axis but Xlabels dont adjust with the bar, I changed the axis([0 5 0 1]) interval but it dosent work:|

Comment: What is the new `X`? Maybe the words are too long? Try `text(1:numel(y), -.05*ones(1,numel(y)), Labels, 'interpreter', 'TeX', 'Fontsize', 8)` (or change `8` as needed)

Comment: Font size, didnt work, I made a trick,I used space in labels s.th like this: '(space here!!)    A_{1}'. and also changed 1:numel(y) to 0.6:numel(y)!!